# Formatting caption in html page

Tags: html, css

I need to be able to center text in the caption with a link added on the far-right of the caption.   Please indicate if/how this can be done.

The caption would be formatted as follows:

```
                          Centered Text                 Right-justified link
```

Comment: Please specify what you mean by “caption” and illustrate your problem with a demo page. Also please specify how JSP is relevant, if it is.

Comment: JSP is completely irrelevant. It's just a HTML code generator. The problem is in the generated HTML/CSS. You would have exactly the same problem when generating HTML with PHP, ASP, JSF, Python, whatever. So I removed the tag.

Answer (score 2):

CSS:

```
.caption {
    text-align: center;    
}
.caption a {
    float: right;    
}
```

Markup:

```
<div class="caption">
    [Centered Caption]
    <a href="#">[Right-justified Link]</a>
</div>​
```

- [**DEMO**](http://jsfiddle.net/paislee/mZXpd/)
- Another [DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/paislee/mZXpd/1/), with caption centered on parent width, as opposed to available space

Comment: Thanks a lot. HTML is in a jsp file of the form <caption "class=caption" text_to_center <a href....> </caption>.  The above works beautifully.

Comment: @user1186233 Cool. You can check mark the answer if it is satisfactory.